# My code that counts vowels separately will not give the value I need. It should return the array.toString() but does not

Tags: java, arrays

Same as title. My code should give the answer [1, 3, 3, 1, 0], but I can't get it to give me any console output.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        vowelCount("i think therefore i am");
    }

    public static int[] vowelCount(String sentence) {
        int[] vowelsCounted = new int[5];
        vowelsCounted.toString();
        for (int i=0; i<sentence.length(); i++) {
        char ch = sentence.charAt(i);
        if (ch == 'a') {
            vowelsCounted[0]++;
        } else if (ch == 'e') {
            vowelsCounted[1]++;
        } else if (ch == 'i') {
            vowelsCounted[2]++;
        } else if (ch == 'o') {
            vowelsCounted[3]++;
        } else if (ch == 'u') {
            vowelsCounted[4]++;
        }
        }
        return vowelsCounted;
    }
}
```

I need some advice on what to do and why it won't give me the answer.
EDIT: This has been answered, I was using the wrong class. It has been changed to:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Exercise17 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(vowelCount("i think therefore i am"));
    }

    public static String vowelCount(String sentence) {
        int[] vowelsCounted = new int[5];
        vowelsCounted.toString();
        for (int i=0; i<sentence.length(); i++) {
        char ch = sentence.charAt(i);
        if (ch == 'a') {
            vowelsCounted[0]++;
        } else if (ch == 'e') {
            vowelsCounted[1]++;
        } else if (ch == 'i') {
            vowelsCounted[2]++;
        } else if (ch == 'o') {
            vowelsCounted[3]++;
        } else if (ch == 'u') {
            vowelsCounted[4]++;
        }
        }
        return Arrays.toString(vowelsCounted) ;

    }
}
```

Comment: I do want to mention that this is in Building Java Programs 3 Chapter 7 Exercise 17, just in case that info is useful.

Comment: Not understanding what you mean by `should return array.toString()` - where are you calling this?

Comment: What I meant was that my method vowelCount runs a process to take a string, detect characters, if it is a vowel then vowelsCounted[0 or 1 or 2 or 3 or 4] ++. This array is returned at the bottom. The book says that my call the the method with the argument "i think therefore i am" should return the equivalent of vowelsCounted.toString().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what you are wanting is

```
public static String vowelCount(String sentence) {
        int[] vowelsCounted = new int[5];
        vowelsCounted.toString();
        for (int i=0; i<sentence.length(); i++) {
        char ch = sentence.charAt(i);
        if (ch == 'a') {
            vowelsCounted[0]++;
        } else if (ch == 'e') {
            vowelsCounted[1]++;
        } else if (ch == 'i') {
            vowelsCounted[2]++;
        } else if (ch == 'o') {
            vowelsCounted[3]++;
        } else if (ch == 'u') {
            vowelsCounted[4]++;
        }
        }
        return Arrays.toString (vowelsCounted);
    }
```

Comment: That worked! Thank you so much! I had spent like 45 minutes dumbfounded prior to you. Have a great day!

Answer (score 0):

What you want is the Arrays.toString(int[]) method:

There is a static Arrays.toString helper method for every different primitive java type; the one for int[] says this:

```
public static String toString(int[] a)
```

Returns a string representation of the contents of the specified array. The string representation consists of a list of the array's elements, enclosed in square brackets ("[]"). Adjacent elements are separated by the characters ", " (a comma followed by a space). Elements are converted to strings as by String.valueOf(int). Returns"null" if a is null.

Comment: does 
public static String vowelCount(String sentence)
 have the same affect with the rest of my code. I applied this and everything went red.

Comment: In your case you have to replace `vowelsCounted.toString()` to `Arrays.toString(vowelsCounted)` and import the corresponding package `java.util.Arrays`

Comment: That was the case. Thanks!